# how does this make syntax work?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am new to makefile. I have a makefile with following statement:

```
....

all: prepare hreader $(DIRS)
    echo $(DIRS)

.PHONY: prepare hreader $(DIRS)

prepare:                              
    mkdir -p ./lib
    $(MAKE) -C game_proc prepare     #here, why 'prepare'?!

hreader:
    make -C extra/hreader

$(DIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@
```

In my makefile directory, i have a 'game_proc' directory. And from GNU make tutorial, i know that below lines

```
prepare:                           
    mkdir -p ./lib
    $(MAKE) -C game_proc
```

will do a recursive make on 'game_proc'.

But why 'prepare' also appear in the recipe? Now how do i interpret '$(MAKE) -C game_proc prepare'? It does a recursive make on 'game_proc', and what? also a recursive make on 'prepare'?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A phony target just tells make that the rule is not going to create an output file of that name.

**Update after comments**

Ok, it's important to realize that there are two separate makefiles here at play:

```
./Makefile
```

and

```
game_proc/Makefile
```

The confusion results from there being a `prepare` target in *both* `Makefile`s.

I.e., there is in `game_proc/Makefile` a target `prepare`. Let's for a moment rename that target to `prepare2` so that the situation becomes clearer:

`./Makefile:`

```
    .PHONY: prepare hreader $(DIRS)

prepare:                              
    mkdir -p ./lib
    $(MAKE) -C game_proc prepare2 # refers to game_proc/Makefile's prepare2 target
```

`game_proc/Makefile:`

```
prepare2:
    ...
```

Comment: but this does not seem to answer my question, does it? could you elaborate more

Comment: Ah, I think I now understand what you mean. Are you concerned about what $(MAKE) -C game_proc prepare does when prepare has been declared phony? It has no effect there, because the phony declaration is valid for the *current* makefile only, not the Makefile in game_proc that the submake is going to be reading.

Comment: i've updated my question in the post. basically i don't understand why 'prepare' should show up in recipe in addition to target. and now with recipe being '$(MAKE) -C game_proc prepare', what does it do? a recursive make of 'game_proc', and?

Comment: I just edited my answer to make this a bit clearer. Sorry about not understanding your question correctly at first

Comment: So just to make the obvious explicit, a plain "make" runs the first target from the Makefile (in yours, that would be the `all` target, which is a common convention), and "make target" makes the target named "target" from the Makefile.  If you have a recipe "`tryme:`" in your Makefile then `make tryme` will run those commands (and, by implication, create or update the file `tryme` in the current directory; although if it is declared a `.PHONY: tryme` then no file is involved).

Comment: @user1816548 omg, you're absolutely right, there IS a 'prepare' in game_proc/Makefile. So $(MAKE) -C game_proc prepare is only going to make 'prepare' in game_proc/Makefile?

Comment: @tripleee GNU tutorial only says '$(MAKE) -C dir' will do a recursive make for dir. i thought it means make the 1st target in dir/Makefile. But according to what you guys said, if the syntax is '$(MAKE) -C dir target', then it means make 'target' in dir/Makefile, right? Only like this can all make sense!